# Pyspark: creating string with substring and frequency vector

Tags: apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I want to create a string from a list of substrings and a correponding frequency list. E.g. my `df_in` looks like following:

```
+-------------------------+-----------+
|         substr          | frequency |
+-------------------------+-----------+
| ['ham', 'spam', 'eggs'] | [1, 2, 3] |
| ['foo', 'bar']          | [2, 1]    |
+-------------------------+-----------+
```

And I want my `df_out` to look like this:

```
+--------------------------------+
|             output             |
+--------------------------------+
| 'ham spam spam eggs eggs eggs' |
| 'foo foo bar'                  |
+--------------------------------+
```

Since the dataset is very large (~22Mio rows), I would like to avoid for-loops whereever possible. 
Is there any elegant way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot!

Edit:
My current approach:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
import pyspark.sql.types as T

def create_text(l_sub, l_freq):
    l_str = [(a+' ')*b if isinstance(b, int) else (a+' ') for a, b in zip(l_sub, l_freq)]
    return ''.join(l_str)

create_str = F.udf(lambda x, y: create_text(x, y), T.StringType())
df = df.withColumn('output', create_str(df_in.sbustr, df_in.frequency))
```

Problem:

I read that in order to speed up the compute, UDFs should be re-written into pyspark way. I do not know how that can be done though. 
Also I found out the `dtype` of `df_in.frequency` is `array<decimal(4.0)>`. So I am trying to either convert these values to `int` first or cast them to `int` in runtime.

Comment: can you use spark 2.40+?

Comment: Yes I can, I also added my current approach in the Edit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if the following works for you:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import expr

df.withColumn('output', expr('''
        array_join(flatten(zip_with(`substr`, `frequency`, (x,y) -> array_repeat(x,int(y)))), ' ')
    ''')).show(truncate=False)
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+
|substr           |frequency|output                      |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+
|[ham, spam, eggs]|[1, 2, 3]|ham spam spam eggs eggs eggs|
|[foo, bar]       |[2, 1]   |foo foo bar                 |
+-----------------+---------+----------------------------+
```

Below is how it works:

- use `zip_with` to iterate two arrays `substr`(as `x`) and `frequency`(as `y`) side-by-side and run `array_repeat(x, int(y))` on each combination to create an array of `y` repeats of `x`.
- flatten the array of arrays
- join the 1-D array of StringType with space

Comment: Thank you for the response!
However it gives following error: 
`pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: "cannot resolve 'zip_with('substr', 'frequency', lambdafunction(array_repeat(`x`, int(`y`)), `x`, `y`))' due to argument data type mismatch: argument 1 requires array type, however, ''substr'' is of string type. argument 2 requires array type, however, ''freqeuncy'' is of string type.;`
I am sure that the `substr` and `frequency` are array type, it seems that those two arguments are interpreted as strings rather than as respective cols in `df_in`

Comment: @zyw92 you need `backtick` to enclose `substr` and `frequency` not single-quotes, since `substr` is a reserved keyword in pyspark, that's why I enclosed both fields using the back ticks. check if you can fix this issue first

Comment: It worked! I made the stupid mistake thinking the ` was typo and replaced them with '.

Comment: I would like to, but my reputation is not high enough to give you upvote.
Your answer has already been accepted :)